# API data call not displaying data in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, database, api, axios

Data doesn't seem to be showing in my table for a Axios API call within react believe the error is related to this console error below.

Following a YT tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AcYhi08e404

Cannot Read properties of undefined (Reading 'map')]

APP.JS

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import { ThemeProvider } from './context/ThemeContext';
import Home from './pages/Home';
import Signin from './pages/Signin';
import Signup from './pages/Signup';
import Account from './pages/Account';
import axios from 'axios';

function App() {
    const [coins, setCoins] = useState([]);
  
    useEffect(() => {
      axios.get(
          'https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=gbp&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=10&page=1&sparkline=true'
        )
        .then(res => {
          setCoins(res.data);
          console.log(res.data);
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
    }, []);
  



  return <ThemeProvider>
    <Navbar />
    <Routes>
  <Route path='/' element={<Home coins={coins} />} />
  <Route path='/signin' element={<Signin />} />
  <Route path='/signup' element={<Signup />} />
  <Route path='/account' element={<Account />} />
    </Routes>
    </ThemeProvider>;
}

export default App;


COINSEARCH.JSX
    
    import React  from 'react';
    import CoinItem from './CoinItem';
    
    
    
    const CoinSearch = ({ coins }) => {
        return (
          <div>
            <div>
            <h1>Search</h1>
            <form>
              <input type="text" placeholder='Search'/>
            </form>
          </div>
    
          <table className='w-full border-collapse text-center'>
            <thead>
              <tr className='border-b'>
                <th></th>
                <th className='px-4'>#</th>
                <th className='text-left'>Coin</th>
                <th></th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>24h</th>
                <th className='hidden md:table-cell'>24h Volume</th>
                <th className='hidden sm:table-cell'>Mkt</th>
                <th>Last 7 Days</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
              {coins.map((coin) => (
                <CoinItem key={coin.id} coin={coin} />
              ))}
              </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        );
      };
    
    export default CoinSearch;
    
    
    COINITEM.JSX
    
    import React from 'react'
    import { AiOutlineStar } from 'react-icons/ai'
    import { Sparklines, SparklinesLines } from 'react-sparklines';
    
    export const CoinItem = ({coin}) => {
      return (
        <tr>
        <td>
          <AiOutlineStar />
        </td>
        <td>{coin.market_cap_rank}</td>
        <td>
          <div>
            <img src={coin.image} alt={coin.id} /> 
            <p>{coin.name}</p>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>{coin.symbol}</td>
        <td>{coin.current_price}</td>
        <td>{coin.price_change_percentage_24h}</td>
        <td>{coin.total_volume}</td>
        <td>{coin.market_cap}</td>
        <td>
          <Sparklines data={coin.sparkline_in_7d.price}>
            <SparklinesLines color='green' />
          </Sparklines>
        </td>
    </tr>
      );
    };

export default CoinItem;
```

Reasonably new to react and struggling to get past this hurdle, any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In Initial render, coin is undefined until it fetches the data , so use shortcircuit condition in COIN component

```
           <tbody>
              <tr>
              // map through coins only if its defined..
              {coins && coins.map((coin) => (
                <CoinItem key={coin.id} coin={coin} />
              ))}
              </tr>
            </tbody>
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the response and answer, that seems to of got rid of the error I was seeing in the console but no data is being pulled into the table. Back to the drawing table I guess!

Answer (score 0):

you are sending props to your home component in App.js can you show me your home component

Comment: Sure, here the code from my home component.



import React from 'react'
import CoinSearch from '../components/CoinSearch'

export const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <CoinSearch />
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home;

Comment: ok, problem is here your are sending props to home component in App.js and in home component you are not getting props or passing it to Coin Search components.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is data is not reaching CoinSearch component because in home component you are not getting props. your code for home component will be this.

```
import React from 'react' 
import CoinSearch from '../components/CoinSearch'

 export const Home = ({coins}) => {
 return ( 
   <div> 
      <CoinSearch coins = {coins} /> 
   </div> 
) 
} 
export default Home;
```

try this piece of code in home component hopefully it will work.